# the linear association was different when selecting 3 knots compared to 4 knots in restricted cubic spline based on cox regression model

Tags: anova, linear, splines

[image]I applied the restricted cubic spline term of BMI/weight in cox regression to test the linear association between BMI/weight with the outcome. However, the P-value of linear association tested by ANOVA was less than 0.05 for weight when selecting 3 knots, was larger than 0.05 when selecting 4 knots. The R-square was the same for the two models. Now I'm confused if the linear association between weight and the outcome is supported. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are testing for nonlinearity, not really testing for "linear association".  Your results make sense.  When you add parameters to a model, unless the parameters pick up a large new effect, you can lose power by diluting effects into more degrees of freedom.  But it is not a good idea to look a multiple P-values in this way, as you will have model uncertainty and poor operating characteristics as a result.  Pre-specify the number of knots and stick with that number.  Base the pre-specification on

- if you know from other data that the relationship is linear set knots to zero (linear fit)
- if you know from other data that the relationship is complex, and especially if it is known to be non-monotonic, choose a relatively large number of knots such as 5
- otherwise pre-specify the number of knots to be what the sample size can afford

The [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms) goes into details.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! But what do you mean by "model uncertainty"? The only difference between the two models was the number of knots, i.e, 3 and 4 knots.

Comment: When I used the log-transformed weight instead of its original scale in that model, the P-value turned to larger than 0.05. My question is: is it normal to use the log-transformed variable in the spline regression?

Comment: You are engaged in model uncertainty by having a data-driven strategy instead of using prespecification.  Model uncertainty involves phantom degrees of freedom that "haunt" the final analysis when you interpret the final analysis as if it were pre-specified.   The result is that P-values and confidence intervals loose their meaning.   For example, when you claim that the type I assertion probability $\alpha$ is 0.05 it can be much larger than 0.05, and claimed confidence interval coverage is overconfident.  Read the classic paper by Grambsch and O'Brien which I summarize in the RMS notes.